# Collect information in mobile application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xamarin, mobile-application

I develop a mobile application using Xamarin Framework.

I want to collect some information during mobile application is running and send it to some receiver. Information is a message `[Event, Action, Arguments (Name-Value pair list)]`.

Now, I have big static class with many methods which are invoked in different places of application. This allows me to have strong typed messages and their arguments. Problem: it is difficult to maintain many similar methods and string constants.

Is there any design pattern to do these things... Maybe I should to store all allowed messages in an XML file and generate c# methods automatically... How is this usually done?

Comment: You will probably have more success on the Programmers Exchange.

Comment: Can I share question to Programmers Exchange, or I should to copy/paste it?

Comment: I think copy and pasting it over then deleting this one would be your best bet. I am really surprised no one flamed you for putting it on here.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think your question is fine.

Here is how I would design your class, which I wouldn't make static.

```
enum Event { /* names here */ }
enum Action  { /* names here */ }
class Arguments { / * properties here for each possible argument */ }

interface IServer { /* include methods on server class */ }

class Server : IServer
{
    public Task Send(Event evt, Action action, Arguments args) { /* code here */ }
}
```

A couple of points here:

- Use enums instead of strings everywhere possible
- If you have a list of possible arguments, make a class with a property for each one. This way you don't have to remember any names or make a class full of constants.
- I return a Task from the method, so you can use async/await
- I don't like static classes, because I prefer to use some kind of service location or IoC container. Such as [this class](https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/blob/master/FieldService/FieldService/Utilities/ServiceContainer.cs) from the Field Service Sample App.
- Statics also don't play nice on Android unless you handle them properly.
- Use an interface to give you flexibility of swapping out the class later. You can also write unit tests against a fake server if you need to.

Comment: Of course, I know about ioc and static class is an simplification... But there are different actions with different events. Now this logic encapsulates in methods. If I create enums or classes, for 100 events I must implement 100 other enums (or classes) for actions... It is overkill...

Comment: So if the options are to learn 100 magic strings or have an `enum`, I think the `enum` would be better, right? Then you know you are selecting the right one with no typos.